# Google Earth Engine Multipoint Object export

Tags: export, google-earth-engine

I have a multipoint object that represents my sites and I am trying to export this so I can easily upload them into other scripts, but cannot figure out how. These points were manually selected with the "Add a Marker" feature in the upper left corner of the map.

At first I tried this:
exports.Potential_DTLB = Potential_DTLB;

Then I tried this based off a youtube video :
var sites = ee.FeatureCollection([ Potential_DTLB]);
Map.addLayer(sites, {}, 'Sites');
Export.table.toDrive({ collection: sites, description: 'ExportCSV', fileFormat: 'CSV'});

but no luck. Thanks for any tips!